# How to make system fields mandatory

Tags: content-hub

Any idea how can we make the `system field/property` required in content hub?

I know we can make the custom `field/property/taxonomies` required by going into the schema and select the field and go to the required tab and select the required option.

[image]

For system field Content hub is not allowing me to edit the field.